# Firebase/JSON database structure to reference a data UUID in other part of database

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

### Update

After the answer I got to use fileUID: true, here is how to implement the dynamic key with AngularFire2 and typescript. It could be useful to some people:

```
this.af.database.object(`users/${userID}/submitted-files/`).update({
  [nextFileKey]: true
});
```

Do I need to create a back-reference to userUUID in the files?

### Original question

Here is my current database structure. This question applies in my case at Firebase, but any JSON database would look the same.

```
{
  "users" : {
    "0gIo3Ak2EFbLDSSCMSEpciuWnB83" : {
      "email" : "username@example.com",
      "hasAcceptedTerms" : true,
      "state" : {
        "isProfileComplete" : true
      },
      "submitted-files": { // FILES REFERENCES WILL GO THERE }
    }
  }
}
```

I want my user to be able to upload some files, which will be reviewed then approved by an external watcher script. On file upload, I'd like to create a new `files` area in my Firebase database, to obtain this structure:

```
{
  "files" : {
    "-K_jG4usPu_4yLED7j8L" : {
      "fileUUID" : "448f4sd8f4sd4fsdf494ds84f98sd4f",
      "filename" : "document.pdf"
      "user" : "0gIo3Ak2EFbLDSSCMSEpciuWnB83"
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "0gIo3Ak2EFbLDSSCMSEpciuWnB83" : {
      "email" : "username@example.com",
      "hasAcceptedTerms" : true,
      "state" : {
        "isProfileComplete" : true
      },
      "submitted-files": { // FILES REFERENCES WILL GO THERE }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is to link now the file UUID in the `user/submitted-files` path.

In perfect world I'd add this to the user data:

```
"submitted-files" : {
    "-K_jG4usPu_4yLED7j8L",
    "SecondFileUUID"
    "ThirdFileUUID"
  }
```

But since I must enter a key/value pair as it's JSON Database, how can I efficiently, in my users part list all submitted files UUID without any other non-required information?

**Do I have to replicate the whole file information in the user path to obtain**:

```
"users" : {
    "0gIo3DQ9EFbLDSSCMSEpciuWnB83" : {
      ...
      "submitted-files" : {
        "-K_jG4usPu_4yLED7j8L" : {
           "fileUUID" : "448f4sd8f4sd4fsdf494ds84f98sd4f",
           "filename" : "document.pdf"
           "user" : "0gIo3Ak2EFbLDSSCMSEpciuWnB83"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

or **is there any way to only enter the reference to file UUID in the `user/submitted-files` path?**

I want advices on structuring my database in a correct "JSON way" good-practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close with:

```
"submitted-files" : {
    "-K_jG4usPu_4yLED7j8L",
    "SecondFileUUID"
    "ThirdFileUUID"
}
```

Just assign them a value of true instead:

```
"submitted-files" : {
    "-K_jG4usPu_4yLED7j8L": true,
    "SecondFileUUID": true,
    "ThirdFileUUID": true
}
```

They explain this in a few of their tutorials.

Comment: Ok seems pretty cool. In good practices, do I have now to create a back reference to user id in files part?